# How to remove the seam between divs in a flex container

Tags: html, css

```css
.main {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #0c0c0c;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

[image: result image]

You can see white seams between divs.

The problem only happens in mobile phone view. Please copy into your text editor and open by chrome and press F12 to toggle to mobile phone view. Stackoverflow snippet doesn't recurrence the problem.

Comment: Chrome `Ctrl + 0` should fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a problem. It's just your chrome dev tools fit level set to `89%` that looks like with white seams. When you toggle your site and set fit level just to `100%`.

Answer (score 1):

I was stumped for a min, but I believe this is your answer:

```
.main {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #0c0c0c;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #0c0c0c;
}
```

I left the margin at 0px but this could possibly be removed without affecting the overall result. I think the div borders were defaulting to grey, so I over-wrote that to the same colour as your main divs.

Answer (score 0):

```
.main {
  background-color: #0c0c0c;
}
```

> This is the solution for your problem.